# Special characters (é, ê, etc.) won't display correcly when writing output in Python 3.8 and xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, text

I am using several text files to write output to an Excel file.
Everything is working fine, except the formatting of special characters like é, ê, etc.

Here is an example of the input text file:

*Please encourage Nehvandré to read aloud more often.*

This is how the specific piece of text is written to the Excel file:

*Please encourage NehvandrÃ© to read aloud more often.*

Here is the code I used to iterate through the text files and write the contents of the files to the Excel file.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import xlsxwriter

txt_dir = r"D:\PYTHON_SCRIPTS\****\comment_output"
subfolder_name = [f.name for f in os.scandir(txt_dir) if f.is_dir()]
subfolder_path = [f.path for f in os.scandir(txt_dir) if f.is_dir()]

sub_index = 0
while sub_index < len(subfolder_name):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(subfolder_path[sub_index] + f"\\{subfolder_name[sub_index]}.xlsx")
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for file in Path(subfolder_path[sub_index]).glob("*.txt"):
        with open(file, "r") as txt_file:
            encoded_file = file.read_text()
            worksheet.write(row, col, file.name[:-4])
            worksheet.write(row, col + 1, encoded_file)
            row += 1
        os.remove(file)
    workbook.close()
    sub_index += 1
```

How can I make the text in the Excel file appear the same as the text in the TXT file?
I am using Python 3.8

Comment: You should definitely look at Unicode.
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_unicode_python3.html

Comment: This (and the following example) is probably a better example from the docs since it deals with reading text files: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_unicode_polish_utf8.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I stumbled upon another way to choose the correct encoding when opening the file:

with open(file, encoding="utf-8", mode="r") as txt_file:

This did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments of Enetrati and jmcnamara pointed me in the correct direction, I set the encoding of the text file when opening it:

```
 with open(file, encoding="utf-8", mode="r") as txt_file:
```

After this change the output was exactly as intended.